# Test instances always classified in to the the same class

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka, text-classification, j48

I have written a java program that build a J48 classifier using training set. Then I pass a test instance to the classifier to predict the unknown class. But each and every test instance classified in to first element of the class attribute.

example : -   if I declare element of class attributes,

```
  cls.add("positive");
  cls.add("negative");
```

In this order, each instance classified in to first class element which is positive.

If I declare class element in this order,

```
cls.add("negative");
cls.add("positive");
```

each instance classified in to first class element which is negative.

My training set shows more than 90% accuracy in weka explore.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     StringToWordVector filter = new StringToWordVector();

    //training set
    BufferedReader reader;
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/suicideTest.arff"));

    Instances train = new Instances(reader);
    train.setClassIndex(train.numAttributes() -1);
    filter.setInputFormat(train);
    train = Filter.useFilter(train, filter);

    reader.close();

    J48 nb = new J48();
    nb.buildClassifier(train);

    ArrayList cls = new ArrayList(2);

    cls.add("positive");
    cls.add("negative"); 

    Attribute clsAtt = new Attribute("class", cls);

    //ArrayList<String> tweet = new ArrayList(1);
    //String tweet = "";
    //Attribute tweetAtt = new Attribute("tweet", tweet);

    ArrayList allAtt = new ArrayList(2); 
    //allAtt.add(tweetAtt);
    allAtt.add(new Attribute("tweet", (FastVector) null));
    allAtt.add(clsAtt);


    // Create an empty test set
     Instances testSet = new Instances("", allAtt, 1);
    // Set class index
    testSet.setClassIndex(testSet.numAttributes() - 1);

    String names=  "Fox News Devotes a Whole Evening[']s Worth of Programming to Whining About CNNAgain (column by @justinbaragona)";
    Instance inst = new DenseInstance(2); 
    inst.setValue((Attribute)allAtt.get(0), names.toString());

    testSet.add(inst);
    System.out.println(testSet.instance(0).toString());
    double pred = nb.classifyInstance(testSet.instance(0));

    filter.setInputFormat(testSet);
    testSet = Filter.useFilter(testSet, filter);

    String predictString = testSet.classAttribute().value((int) pred);

    System.out.println(predictString);
}
```

my training set look like

```
@RELATION suicidalideation

@ATTRIBUTE tweet string
@ATTRIBUTE class {positive,negative}

@DATA

"is it weird to be tired of living. i just. don't want to exist for a while", positive
"I don't want to exist", positive
"i don't want to exist in this world without you", positive
"I simply just don't want to exist anymore.", positive
"I don't want to exist im fed up of all this shit", positive
"I am deeply sad that i don't want to exist now", positive
"It's feel like I don't want to exist to anybody life", positive
"fuck me up i don't want to exist for myself", positive
"I don't want to be alone, I don't want to be in my room, I don't want to exist", positive
"I just kind of don't want to exist right now cause stress is just too much", positive
"if i'm going to be a problem i don't want to exist", positive
"If he leaves me I don't want to go on anymore..will jump to running train ..", positive
"Im dead inside and I don't want to go on.", positive
"I don't want to go on living in this world without you", positive
"I hate my life and Don't want to go on further", positive
"I dont want to go on living in this world without you", positive
"Wance&Forall | Coming SoonnHow soon depends on you!nLIKE/FOLLOW Wance & Forall on "    , negative
"RT @ChampionsLeague: Zidane: Toughest opponent? Scholes. The complete midfielder; undoubtedly the greatest midfielder of his generation.[...]" , negative
"You are excited to participate in activities with people who m... "    , negative
"RT @pussypun: rub ur ass against his dick by accident on purpose"  , negative
"RT @NiallOfficial: Have a great 4th of July , America" , negative
"RT @thedrewpowell: Happy Birthday America! #FourthOfJuly"  , negative
"RT @virtuaIg: she a child sir "    , negative
"Happy 4th of July Fillies!  Good day to play some golf. Coach played 9. How bout you? "    , negative
"@TheEFCForum Fair enough. We will see. But I'm doubting I'm going to be wrong on this to be honest, if I am fair enough."  , negative
"RT @_EVANGELO: We are aware we weren't free on this date. Please shut the entire fuck up and EAT. Gaddamn! Every damn holiday y'all got som[...]"  , negative
"Langley's Abbey Fortin going to bat for Canada #Langley #bhivecan" , negative
"Daily Organic Multivitamins for Kids GLUTEN FREE - SUGAR FREE - VEGAN - KOSHER - HALAL VITAMIN SUPPLEMENTS  Nutra Pharmnmultivitamin has 45"   , negative
"RT @skinupgg:  ST SSG 08 DRAGONFIRE GIVEAWAY OH MY GOD nnIT'S SO LIT nTO ENTERnn[?] RETWEET & FOLLOWn[?] " , negative
"RT @DerekCressman: Happy July 4th. Let's Declare American Independence from Russian interference in our sovereignty"   , negative
"RT @wordstionary: Never let your past dictate your future. It's never too late to become better."  , negative
"RT @Jon_Wienke: Stopped to clean his sign. Nothing but respect for my president. " , negative
"@Ayindeemu Please help my friend win the @isokenmovie #IsokenMegaGiveaway contest by liking the tweet above    Please!n @_idarahh" , negative
"RT @politicques: What to The Slave is 4th of July? -- 1841 Speech by Frederick Douglass -- Courtesy of The Freeman Institute... "  , negative
"idk why that bothers me"   , negative
"RT @JPY_Kurdish: Stoke-on-Trent, England: [?] pedophile hunter group catches a Muslim man who wants to meet a 13-year-old girl for sex at Cen[...]"    , negative
"@Danny_Draws Hah, that's very Portland. I wonder if it affects water pressure. :)" , negative
"RT @CSGORoll: AK-47 | Case Hardened FTnn- RTn- Follown- Enable notifications on CSGORolln- Play "  , negative
"Nobody can go back... Maria Robinson #quote #quotes #inspiration #findyourhappily "    , negative
"RT @ManuBlinkVIP: Rosé talking about IU again! You're doing great sweetie, keep mentioning that, this collab must happen!" , negative
"need to be as lit as the fireworks tonight"    , negative
"@RyderDanielz @davey_sap ...I think he would be a great opponent for me at 'Chantz Of A Lifetime' for my titles."  , negative
"RT @RealNiggy_: well if you move i could see all my options "  , negative
"@Komangsrie21 polback donv"    , negative
"RT @PeadaPipper: Easy Breezy Beautiful.  " , negative
```

Comment: How does your train data looks?

Comment: @GrayCygnus my training data set has more than 25k tuples.

Comment: Ok could you add an excerpt that to your question? I can see that the comment you posted the first element ("is it weird to be...") does not have a class tag at the beginning, unlike the others, could that be the error you get?

Comment: @GrayCygnus I have add part of my training set to my question.